# Table Cell TextLabel frame width increasing automatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I wish to have a table with some label and then I add a text field UI after the label.
I want the Label to be of some fixed size (say 150) and the rest of the cell width be occupied by the textfield.

Hence I set the frame of my cell.textLabel in function

> cellForRowAtIndexPath

in this way

```
[cell.textLabel setFrame:CGRectMake(cell.textLabel.frame.origin.x, cell.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 150, cell.textLabel.frame.size.height)];
```

but this doesnt seem to work.

Any ideas why and What could be my solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why don't you add custom lable on your cell...

```
UILabel *mylabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5,5, 150, 40)];
[cell.contentView addSubview:mylabel];
```

Otherwise you need to override -`LayoutSubViews` method and have to subclass `UITableViewCell`..

Answer (score 1):

With a `UITableViewCell` its responsible for laying out its subviews.  You have a very high level control over its layout using the [`UITableViewCellStyle`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITableViewCellStyle) enum.

If you want something custom, override UITableViewCell and add view to its content view or modify existing views.  When you do this, be sure to do the layout in the `layoutSubviews` method, e.g.

```
- (void)layoutSubviews 
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(self.textLabel.frame.origin.x, 
                                      self.textLabel.frame.origin.y, 
                                      150, 
                                      self.textLabel.frame.size.height);
}
```

The cell's frame will change when its added to the UITableView.  When the cell's frame changes layoutSubviews is called to give you a chance to adjust its subviews.  By default the UITableViewCell will do some if its own adjustments which is what was probably causing your issue.